# In SQL Server 2005, can I take multiple db snapshots at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, snapshot, backupexec

We're setting up K2 and it requires that several databases be snapshoted before being backed up so that they are at the exact same point in time.  Can I do this and how?  There are a total of 14 databases that need backed up.

Answer (score 3):

If you want them backed up at the exact same point in time, you could put them all into single user mode, back them up, and return them to multi-user mode.

The recommended maximum number of DB snapshots is approximately 10, and not intended to be used quite how you are proposing to use them.

Comment: Agreed - even snapshots don't guarantee transactional integrity across databases.  Snapshot creation is very quick, but it's not instant, so using snapshots isn't the best solution if they need to be from exactly the same moment.  Single user mode is really your only option.

Comment: Single user mode won't really work either because this is going to kill our server.  Thinking about this more, I don't know how anything could do it...

Comment: "because this is going to kill our server" ?? what do you mean? If you want a precise pointin time state across a number of Dbs, the only way to guarantee this is to get the users out of those DBs!

Comment: The requirement came down the pipe to me.  by 'Kill our server' I mean that we can't stop people from editing the data at the same time.  I'm starting to believe what they actually want is a way to recover to a specific point in time with both db's and apparently Symantec backup exec allows that.